# pyserial, if and file read

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a stupid python problem.

I'm trying to read a line from a file everytime i get a 'READY' message from a serial connection so i wrote this :

```
import serial
from time import sleep

port = "/dev/tty.usbserial-A400fYTT"
speed = 57600
polarfile = 'polarfile.pg'

f = open(polarfile, 'r')

ser = serial.Serial(port, speed, timeout=0)

while True:
    data = ser.read(9999)
    if len(data) > 0:
        if(data == 'READY'):
            f.readline()
        else:
            sleep(0.5)

    sleep(1)

ser.close()
```

But it doesn't work, however if i replace the if(data == 'READY' block by print data. I get the READY message.

Also i can read my file with f.readline()...

Thanks to give advice to a py newbie

--
edit : 
Important info, the serial doesn't receive only "READY" message, but a bunch of other, but i want just to react when the "READY" messsage is received.

Comment: Ok it seems that i found out the problem.

This is not a problem with the python code but the message received on the serial line.

It's not just "READY" but a more complex string like "READY\n" or other new line stuff.

I don't know which one but i'll found out.

Sorry for the noise !

Comment: Just in case your script receives more data than just `'READY'`, such as a new line character or other messages, you could use `if 'READY' in data:`. Another (traditional) method would be to read one character at a time with a non-zero timeout value and progressively build the message `'READY'` and starting over when it doesn't match.

Comment: thanks that's almost what i did :  replace `data = ser.read(9999)` by `data = ser.readline(9999)` which gives me the message line by line instead of second by second of input data and then replace `if( data == 'READY' ):` by `if (data.startswith('READY')):` and now it works :)

Comment: if you've resolved the problem you should mark it as solved.

Comment: how ? i don't have enough reputation to send a reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replace

data = ser.read(9999)

by

`data = ser.readline(9999)` which gives me the message line by line instead of second by second of input data and then replace

`if( data == 'READY' ):`by

`if (data.startswith('READY')):`

and now it works :)